# How to get IpAddress while connect by cable

Tags: wifi, ip-address

It's a table , My company assemble it,with no wifi no sim，but cable;
Now , how could i get Ipaddress and other configs?

I can't use WifiManager/WifiInfo ...

Answer (score 0):

Because of connected by cable;    we can't use WifiManger;     i found Linux Shell could help;

but not what i know much.

```
private String do_exec(String cmd) {
        String s = "\n";
        try {
            String[] cmdline = {"sh", "-c", cmd};
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                s += line + "\n";
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("do_exec", s);
        return s;
    }
```